# Propagating the `trace_id` and `span_id` with `opentelemetry` and `tracing`

Tags: rust, open-telemetry, rust-tracing, rust-tonic

I have a client and a server, both instrumented with `tracing`, and the `opentelemetry_otlp` exporter also works correctly as far as I can tell. To test that I have set up the docker-compose example of Grafana Tempo as a receiver and the traces show up correctly.

However, a call from the client to the server results in two distinct traces, one for the client and one for the server, and I'd like to associate them into a single trace, by propagating the trace context from the client, and injecting it on the server.

My problem however is that there appear to be hundreds of ways to get this done, and they all contradict. And my understanding of the interaction between `tracing` and `opentelemetry` is a bit nebulous. I would expect that registering the `OpenTelemetryLayer` as a subscriber to `tracing` would result in the opentelemetry span being managed alongside the `tracing` span, but whenever I try to extract the `SpanContext` in order to serialize it and attach it to the `tonic` query as an HTTP header, the `SpanContext` is uninitialized (i.e., it has the invalid `trace_id=00000000000000000000000000000000` and `span_id=0000000000000000`, which isn't allowed.

The following minimal example shows what will eventually be the client, attempting to extract the `SpanContext`, but until I can get the `SpanContext` there is no point in continuing.

```rust
use opentelemetry::{
    runtime,
    sdk::{
        trace::{BatchConfig, RandomIdGenerator, Tracer},
        Resource,
    },
    trace::TraceContextExt,
    KeyValue,
};
use opentelemetry_otlp::WithExportConfig;
use opentelemetry_semantic_conventions::{resource::SERVICE_NAME, SCHEMA_URL};
use tracing_opentelemetry::OpenTelemetryLayer;
use tracing_subscriber::{layer::SubscriberExt, util::SubscriberInitExt};

fn init_tracer(resource: Resource, endpoint: &str) -> Tracer {
    opentelemetry_otlp::new_pipeline()
        .tracing()
        .with_trace_config(
            opentelemetry::sdk::trace::Config::default()
                .with_id_generator(RandomIdGenerator::default())
                .with_resource(resource),
        )
        .with_exporter(
            opentelemetry_otlp::new_exporter()
                .http()
                .with_timeout(std::time::Duration::from_secs(1))
                .with_endpoint(endpoint),
        )
        .with_batch_config(BatchConfig::default())
        .install_batch(runtime::Tokio)
        .unwrap()
}

fn init_tracing_subscriber(service_name: &str, endpoint: &str) -> OtelGuard {
    eprintln!("Initializing tracing with endpoint {}", endpoint);
    let resource = Resource::from_schema_url(
        [KeyValue::new(SERVICE_NAME, service_name.to_owned())],
        SCHEMA_URL,
    );

    tracing_subscriber::registry()
        .with(tracing_subscriber::filter::EnvFilter::from_default_env())
        .with(tracing_subscriber::fmt::layer().compact())
        .with(OpenTelemetryLayer::new(init_tracer(resource, endpoint)))
        .try_init()
        .unwrap();
    OtelGuard {}
}

fn init() -> OtelGuard {
    let service_name = dbg!(env!("CARGO_PKG_NAME"));
    let endpoint = "http://172.18.0.2:4318/v1/traces";
    init_tracing_subscriber(service_name, endpoint)
}

pub struct OtelGuard {}
impl Drop for OtelGuard {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        opentelemetry::global::shutdown_tracer_provider();
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let _guard = init();
    a().await;
}

#[tracing::instrument]
async fn a() {
    aa();
    bb()
}

#[tracing::instrument]
fn aa() {}
#[tracing::instrument]
fn bb() {
    dbg!(opentelemetry::Context::current().span());
}
```

What am I missing? How can I get the current `opentracing` `SpanContext` so that I can propagate it to the client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there! Check the [OpenTelemetrySpanExt](https://docs.rs/tracing-opentelemetry/latest/tracing_opentelemetry/trait.OpenTelemetrySpanExt.html) trait from the `tracing_opentelemetry` crate.

It provides `context` on the sending side:

```
use opentelemetry::global as otel;
use opentelemetry_http::HeaderInjector;

use tracing::Span;
use tracing_opentelemetry::OpenTelemetrySpanExt;

let ctx = Span::current().context();

otel::get_text_map_propagator(|propagator| {
    propagator.inject_context(&ctx, &mut HeaderInjector(req.headers_mut()));
});
```

The receiving side uses `set_parent` from the same trait:

```
let extractor = opentelemetry_http::HeaderExtractor(headers);
let remote_context = otel::get_text_map_propagator(|propagator| propagator.extract(&extractor))
span.set_parent(remote_context);
```

See [opentelemetry-remote-context](https://github.com/tokio-rs/tracing-opentelemetry/blob/62690b4ac9c1065de61aa82d763a83bb2790cf81/examples/opentelemetry-remote-context.rs) for an example.

Comment: Thanks @mdi, that worked like a charm. One additional caveat to add here is that `tracing` is tracking the state, which ought to be then transformed into opentelemetry. So use `tracing:: Span` rather than `opentelemetry::trace::Span` which is what I was trying to find a path from.